# Get a teams Rank based their xp

Tags: mysql

Table is called teams, need to get the following columns... name, wins, losses, percentage, level, xp WHERE `console` = 3 AND `game` = 23 AND `laddertype` = 1  I'm in need of a Rank column to be included with the dataset.

Comment: Why not just ORDER BY xp then add the rank number in the application?

Comment: I answered a very similar question here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/score-ranking-no-tie-if-tie-order-by-score-submit-date/73170#73170 but I warned that that wasn't MySQL's way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result = mysql_query("SET @Rank := 0");`

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, @Rank := @Rank + 1 AS Rank FROM teams ORDER BY xp DESC, created ASC");`

Comment: that code seemed to do the trick